# I'm getting exception, not sure why

Tags: android, eclipse

This is what I did now:

```
public class AndroidTestToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;
    private ArrayList<String> itemsList;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private String contry_name;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    private TextView textview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("----------",Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
        itemsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsList.add(Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,itemsList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();

            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

       textview.setText(itemsList.get(position));
    }



}
```

I looked on the LogCat but I don't understand what's wrong. 
The exception started being thrown only after I added `textView` and `textView1`, but I can't figure out where the problem is.

This is the error from the LogCat:

```
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testotspeech/com.testotspeech.AndroidTestToSpeechActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.testotspeech.AndroidTestToSpeechActivity
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.testotspeech.AndroidTestToSpeechActivity
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at com.testotspeech.AndroidTestToSpeechActivity.onCreate(AndroidTestToSpeechActivity.java:41)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
06-07 00:12:58.119: E/AndroidRuntime(12887):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 41: `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);`
In this line, you set your current activity (`this`) as an `OnItemSelectedListener` to the spinner but your activity doesn't implement that interface.

Comment: spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this); Right i just used debug now and found that the exception is there. what should i do ? If i remove "this" then im getting error on the OnItemSelectedListener in the ()

Answer (score 2):

Change this line: `textview.setText(itemsList<position>);`
into: `textview.setText(itemsList.get(position));`
Here is the doc: [ArrayList.get(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29)

Comment: I changed no errors but when im running the application im getting exception. Im not sure what is the problem. The exception is came up only now when i added this textView. I will edit my question with the exception.